# Is this strtol example correct in how it handles an uninitialized pointer?

Tags: c

I found an example on using `strtol` over [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtol.htm)- I'll replicate the example here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
   char str[30] = "2030300 This is test";
   char *ptr;
   long ret;

   ret = strtol(str, &ptr, 10);
   printf("The number(unsigned long integer) is %ld\n", ret);
   printf("String part is |%s|", ptr);

   return(0);
}
```

Is the use of the uninitialized pointer in `char *ptr` correct? If so, why isn't this a case of using an uninitialized pointer incorrectly?

Comment: It is alright - it will point to one of the characters of the `*str`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not actually using an uninitialized pointer.  You're passing the address of a local variable, which is known.

The variable `ptr` is of type `char *`, so `&ptr` is of type `char **`, which is what `strtol` expects for its second argument.  The `strtol` function will then dereference this pointer, yielding an lvalue expression (i.e. one you can assign to) of type `char *` to assign an address to `ptr`.

Comment: I see, thanks so much. So `strtol` is taking a ptr, and then assigning to it the address of the first invalid char in `str`.

Answer (score 1):

from `man strtol` we get this

> long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
>
> If endptr is not NULL, strtol() stores the address of the first invalid character in *endptr.  If there were
>          no digits at all, strtol() stores the original value of nptr in *endptr (and returns 0).  In particular,  if
>          *nptr is not '\0' but **endptr is '\0' on return, the entire string is valid.

In your case, you do not pass a NULL pointer because `&ptr` is not NULL, so in case your input string will not be all parsed, after `strtol` finishes, it will mutate the pointer `ptr` to point somewhere inside the input string where there were no more digits but something else.

For example, if you want to extract a long number from the string `123abc` this call will return a long equal to `123` and ptr will be mutated to point on the letter `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Your explanation that the ptr points to the start of the invalid portion of the string clears things up for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of ptr in this instance as an out parameter. You pass in the valid address of the ptr variable on the stack and the function will then write (output) the address of the character that follows the last digit in str.

Comment: It's not an in-out parameter; it is a pure out parameter.  The initial value that the pointer points to is irrelevant. It is set when the function returns (unless you pass a null pointer instead of a pointer to a pointer).